# After WordPress updated, getting error

Tags: wordpress

After updating my client's WordPress site to 4.7 version, could not access the website and wp-admin. I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Roles' not found in /webcorp1/www/corpusers/h/y/hyeinfotech.com/wp-settings.php on line 293

Comment: Have you updated your plugins as well?

Comment: @Jordi..just updated the wordpress only..u got any idea?

Comment: I'd try to deactivate al the plugins to see if the site works. Then activate the plugins one by one to see which one is causing the issue (if any).

Comment: couldnot access the site and admin too..wt to do?

Comment: This can be also done by accessing your `wp-content/plugins` folder via FTP and renaming all plugin folders (e.g. adding an underscore before)

Comment: after did what u said,Now i got this `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_installing() in /webcorp1/www/corpusers/h/y/hyeinfotech.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1231 `

Comment: Then, your research could follow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248969/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp-installing

Comment: oh thanks buddy..Now i got where the fault..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you update WordPress you should follow the [WordPress guideline](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress).

It looks some files are missing related to `user_role class`. Try updating plugins. If issue not solved try following solutions.

**Solution 1:** If you have backup then you can restore the website and try update WordPress once again along with all plugins.

**Solution 2:**

1. Create a demo/test location on the server/local computer.
2. Take backup of wp_content folder.
3. Take backup of Database.
4. Install a fresh wordpress on the test location.
5. Import the database backup on step 3 to test location wordpress database.
6. Replace the content folder on the test location.
7. Check, if everything works fine then you can move the code and database to current running server.

I hope this solution will work for you. If not you can hire any reliable [WordPress Development Agency](https://www.ratnatechnology.com) or Individual to make things done for you.